# Why does the B field saturate in ferromagnetic hysteresis?

Tags: magnetic-fields, ferromagnetism

The typical hysteresis curve results from plotting $B$ and against $H$, e.g. using a Rowland ring. As I understand it, the $H$ field is that resulting from the applied current and is directly proportional to the current, $H = ni$ (and is the same whether or not there is a magnetic material in the core). The $B$ field is the total field resulting from the sum of the magnetization of the material, $M$, and the $H$ field. $B =  \mu_o (M + H) = \mu_o (M + ni)$

I understand that, once the domains in the ferromagnetic material are all aligned, the magnetic material is saturated, M is a maximum. What I don't understand is why $B$ reaches a maximum. As long as i (and therefore $H$) increases, why doesn't $B$ continue to increase (albeit more slowly than when the domains can kick in and ignoring the heating and melting that would occur with very high currents)?

Shouldn't the hysteresis plots indicate that the curves continue beyond the 'end points'?

Am I simply misunderstanding what the $B$ in such plots represents? Or the relationship between $B$ and $H$?

Comment: I would say that you are correct.  M saturates but B does not.  Check the variables on the hysteresis graph.  Keep in mind that M can be much larger than H.

Comment: But it seems to be said that B becomes 'saturated' or at best asymptotic to some value. For example here: https://www.duramag.com/techtalk/tech-briefs/magnetic-saturation-understanding-limitations-to-induced-magnetism-achieved-in-workpiece/ and https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/electromagnetism/magnetic-hysteresis.html

Comment: Notice that in your first reference the vertical axis of the graph represents M.  In the second, the line beyond saturation is sloped.

Comment: I was referring to the explanations rather than the pictures - but I ran out of space quoting them here so I won't. If it were a plot of M (or B due to the material) versus H it would be ok to have asymptote. But actually, I agree with you, I think I am right. B will increase with H after the domains are all lined up. It is the accounts that are confused.